# How to filter (by clicking in a value of a select ) the li elements of an ul that's being created by a javascrip function fom data coming from api

Tags: javascript, filter

I've tried multiple ways, but they just work on li elements that are in the html file and not the ones being created by a javascript function.

the code is here:
https://github.com/inesmm666/forum

The function addAUser in forum.js defines how the li element is going to look like and adds it to the ul with the id("lista-projetos-global") in the forum.html file.
The api rest requests are in the api.js file.

Comment: Hi Ines, it would be helpful if you could add some code, expecially the html code of the page and the javascript code that gets the list item from the API. You can check out this help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, would need to see the code: we need to see how you are referencing the LI elements. The load order is naturally important also.

Comment: @Drago96 https://github.com/inesmm666/forum

Comment: @BluntJackson my code is here (https://github.com/inesmm666/forum), what should I change?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. It would have been better if it was minimal and reproducible, but it's already something to work on :)    To give you an idea of how I would filter it, I would keep the values I retrieve from the api in an array, filter it when needed, and then update all the values in the list. This is a simple example of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/t6x32yjz/

Comment: @Drago96 if I change the fakeApi array to the response of my api request it says: ex.js:141 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: values is not iterable
    at updateDOM (ex.js:141:17)
    at init (ex.js:166:5)
    at ex.js:172:1

Comment: @InêsSilva That code was meant more as a guidance rather then something to copy-paste. You should look at what your api is returning. It must be an array of some sort. Maybe you need to add "await"?

Comment: @Drago96 it returns an ArrayList of DTO's (ArrayList<ForumPublicationDTO> listOfPosts)

Comment: Can you share your updated code? And maybe, do a `console.log` of the data coming from the API

Comment: @Drago96 console log: lista[{"id":1,"description":"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","creatorPublication":"inesmm1996@gmail.com","publicationType":"NECESSITY","title":"New Necessity bla","createDate":"18-06-2022 17:43:12","deleted":false},{"id":2,"description":"bbBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB","creatorPublication":"inesmm1996@gmail.com","publicationType":"IDEA","title":"New Idea bla","createDate":"18-06-2022 17:44:08","deleted":false}, etc ]

Comment: @Drago96 the updated code is the file newForum.js here: https://github.com/inesmm666/forum

Comment: Ok, I've took a look at the code, and I think you should look for some informations about callbacks, promises and asynchronous javascript. The way you're using the "getForumAPI" function will not work, since it's asynchronous, but is used as if it was returning some value. Actually, the `getAPIData` data function will return `null`, and that's why it's not possible to iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

Since new elements are added later after the page has loaded, they also miss the appropriate event listeners you setup for the one already rendered. To solve this, you can take advantage of the event propagation by listening for the event in a common ancestor and this technique is called [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Comment: common ancestor is a ul or a function?

Comment: @InêsSilva a DOM element, in this case `ul` or even higher up until `body`

Comment: if I have a ul in the html file where the li elements are going to be added, is that the  common ancestor?

Comment: should I add an event listener in the html file ul for when the value of the select changes?

Comment: @InêsSilva yes, the ul in the html is the common ancestor, and that where your event listener can go. Be sure to filter for `e.target` value otherwise you’ll be executing your code for all the events that will be bubbling up, no matter what element triggered it